# VMware 上の Ubuntu で USB メモリを扱う方法を教えて下さい

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware, usb

Window11にVMareを入れUbuntu20.04.1を仮想OSとして利用しています。
今、ddコマンドについて学習しています。
cpコマンドとの違いがよくわからなかったので、USBを使ってデータをコピーしてみようと思いつきました（考え方が間違っているのかもしれません）

USBメモリにいくつかのデータを入れてあり、Windows11で確認すると以下のように出ます。通常はここから必要なファイルを取り出したり、新規で作成して保存したりします。

[image: usb ホストOS]

このUSBのデータをLinux上で利用したいと考えています。
Ubuntuのアプリケーション→「ディスク」を選択すると以下のような画面が出ます。

[image: USB Linux]

この状態ではUSB内にどんなデータが入っているのか、あるいはファイル等を作成してここに保存する方法がわかりません。マウントなどの作業が必要なのでしょうか？

検索したり、書籍で調べたりしてみたところ、仮想OS自体のバックアップやUSBからインストールする方法はたくさん出てきますが、普通にデータファイルをコピーしたり、新規作成、あるいはddコマンドを使ってデバイスの一部をバックアップしたいと思っています。

いくつかサイトなどを見てみたのですが何のことかわかりません。
[http://www.edu.tuis.ac.jp/~mackin/java/2008/linux/usb.html](http://www.edu.tuis.ac.jp/%7Emackin/java/2008/linux/usb.html)

Windows上でUSBを利用する時のように、Ubuntu上で利用するにはどのような操作が必要なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

対象の Ubuntu はゲスト OS なので、単に Linux で USB を使う時の話だけではなく、仮想環境での追加作業が必要となります。

具体的には、ゲスト OS に対して USB デバイスを追加し、 (ホスト OS の) USB 接続を認識させる作業が必要です。

VMware の具体的な製品が分かりませんが、例えば以下のドキュメントを参照してみてください。

https://docs.vmware.com/jp/VMware-Workstation-Player-for-Windows/16.0/com.vmware.player.win.using.doc/GUID-E003456F-EB94-4B53-9082-293D9617CB5A.html